# Ruby IDE and the Ruby Version Manager

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use either Aptana or RubyMine. I am using RVM so I can have multiple versions Ruby at once, but when I am starting a new project in either of them I get the 1.8.7, which is not what I want to use. I have installed the latest 1.9.2 and it is this version that I want to use, how do I manage that? (I have set the 1.9.2 as default in command line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In RubyMine you can choose your Ruby version in the menu **Preferences** -> **Ruby SDK and Gems**.

[image]

In RubyMine 4, **Preferences** has been changed to **File -> Settings...**